# Unable to click button - Python / Selenium & bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

Im trying to click a button and tried already several different methods with no avail.

Method 1:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.CLASS_NAME, 'sc-gsDKAQ fWOgSr')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'sc-gsDKAQ fWOgSr'))))
```

Method 2:

```
driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='sc-gsDKAQ fWOgSr').click()
```

Method 3:

```
btn = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='sc-gsDKAQ fWOgSr')
btn.click()
```

Error messages:

M1: Timeout

M2: NoSuchElementException

M3: NoSuchElementException

I tried the same by looking with Xpath, no success. Had another Error in the past, which stated that "String" cannot be interacted with.

Comment: can you confirm the url?

Comment: https://www.immobilienscout24.at/regional/wien/wien/wohnung-kaufen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That element is in a `#shadow root` element, so it's a bit fiddly to reach. Also, page seems to react at mouse movements (and only load after it detect some mouse movement). The following code seems to work: setup is on Linux, but you can adapt it to your own, just observe the imports and the part after defining the browser:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
import time as t


webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

actions = ActionChains(browser)

url = 'https://www.immobilienscout24.at/regional/wien/wien/wohnung-kaufen'

browser.get(url) 

page_title = WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[title='Zur Homepage']")))
actions.move_to_element(page_title).perform()
parent_div = WebDriverWait(browser, 20000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "usercentrics-root"))) 
shadowRoot = browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", parent_div)

try:
    button = WebDriverWait(shadowRoot, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']"))) 
    button.click()
    print('clicked')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print('no click button')
```

This will click the button, and print in the terminal:

```
clicked
```

Comment: I use:
´´´from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager´´´
as the "traditional" way with the preinstalled driver did not work for me, to many errors to handle. Is there a way to adjust that? Basically I need a way to still use the Service without the defined path to the chromedriver

Comment: You can use whaever works on your system - as long as you have setup a functional Selenium/chromeddriver. Just observe the imports above, as well as the part after defining the browser (or driver, if you call it that).

Comment: Yea, those I have, unfortunately I get an error:
´´´TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not WebDriver´´´
Im on MacOS so it should work just haven't figured out how to rewrite your code.

Comment: So you have a working setup, you can for example open the browser and navigate to google.com?

Comment: Yea yea that's all no problem. Its just this specific task when trying to navigate this specific website that I can't manage to make work :( everything else works :D

Comment: If you can access this website, and you imported all packages as above, and you respect the rest of the code, it will work. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, it worked now despite getting now another error with my code :P but the button is getting clicked ;)